# How can I use a standalone openapi.yaml file for swagger UI in spring-boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I am trying to generate my swagger UI with a openapi.yaml file I created but it simply isn't working. **is there additional configuration needed for this to work?**

What I have so far

1. My file is in `myProject/src/main/resources/static/openapi.yaml`
2. In application.properties the following is set...
   `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/openapi.yaml` and
   `springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false`
3. `pom.xml` contains the below

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried a few different configurations and they result in a whitelabel error page for `http://localhost:8082/v3/api-docs` or it shows the swagger page but gives `response status is 401 /openapi.yaml` when I set `springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true`

I have looked at plenty of tutorials and stack overflow post stating that this should work but it just isn't can anyone shed some light on anything I might be missing?

Comment: I believe spring supports openapi yaml generation out of the box based on your implementation. Why do you want to override that? Does not that defeat the purpose of generating docs based on your current implementaiton?

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct but architects insist on having a defined file, not just that I think there are more plans in the future for it. I tried arguing that the generated one is probably better but oh well. There must be a reason they are moving away from the auto-generated implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` in the application property.

see
https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml